# How does the alignment system work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I currently have 1150 dark side points, and 900 light side points.  How long will it take me to reach dark side tier 1?

Comment: it should have a meter for it, u must be nuetral still?

Answer (score 6):

Your LS/DS points cancel each other out so your alignment should be 250 DS points, therefore you need an additional 750 DS points (without any LS points) to reach Tier 1.
[image: Example]

Comment: BTW, it's better to save screenshots as PNGs, not JPEGs, it looks much better.

Comment: @svick The game saves them as JPEGs ;)